# Blend for VS2012 not showing project templates

Tags: wpf, visual-studio-2012, expression-blend

I started using Blend for VS 2012RC and when i open Blend and then go to `New Project`, I can not see the option of selecting the project type. It is totally empty as shown below. Can anyone give me a help to resolve this.

And I also tried to create a WPF project in VS2012RC and opened it in Blend but I can not get the design views.

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What version of windows do you have? It is windows 7 Right? I think the Blend that comes with VS2012 **only** works for Metro Applications templates, so if you are on Windows 7, this templates are not available to you.

**Solution:** for working with WPF/Silverlight templates, you may use the VS2012's designer. VS2012 have a designer very similar to Blend, it is not as good as Blend, but works, and also have several Blend's utilities.

You may also use the old Blend 4 with VS2012 projects that have target framework 4.0 or lower. For more details please see this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13518417/how-to-edit-a-c-sharp-project-in-blend-4-that-was-created-with-vs2012/13518838#13518838).

Hope this could be helpful for you...

Comment: Thanks Raul I did not know that. Can you elaborate on this a bit more.

Comment: Sorry if the first answer were not so elaborated. Please Check the answer now. If there is another more thing that could helps you, please make me know.

Comment: than you very much. got it :)